# Loading a gradle dependency depending on the version of the parent gradle dependency (for making spring boot starter)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I want to create a Spring Boot starter for rest auth using Spring Security.

But I have Spring Boot of different versions (2 or 3) and of differt type (web or reactive).

In this starter I want to load just a certain dependency of Spring Security.

I use gradle and want to do something like that in the build.gradle of my starter:

```
if (parent_spring_dependency == "2" and parent_spring_dependency == "web") {
    implementation("certain-spring-security")
} else if (parent_spring_dependency == "2" and parent_spring_dependency == "reactive") {
    implementation("certain-spring-security")
} else if (...
```

What is the best practice to implement this?